# SwiftData crashes when setting optional String of Codable property

Tags: ios, swift, codable, swift-data

I've run into an issue where setting a property on a SwiftData object to a `Codable` struct with an optional String crashes the app.

For example, if I have the following model object and struct :

```swift
@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    var codableProp: CodedValue?
    
    init(timestamp: Date, cProp: CodedValue?) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
            self.codableProp = cProp
    }
}

struct CodedValue: Codable{
    var string0: String? = nil
    var bool0: Bool? = nil
    var bool1: Bool? = nil
}
```

If I create an instance of `CodedValue` with the following JSON, the app crashes:

```json
{
    "bool0": true
}
```

The specific error I'm getting is:

> "Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional<Swift.String>' (0x1c1e3f000) to 'Swift.String' (0x1c1e37e30)"

The crash seems to occur somewhere within the `@Model` macro:
[image: The expanded @Model macro, showing the line where the crash occurs]

Comment: Remove the `= nil` initialisers from your `CodedValue` struct

Comment: After doing that, the issue still occurs

Comment: How are you creating the instant of `CodedValue` from the Json?  Where does it crash?  Which line?

Comment: Does it work at all to use custom types as property types in SwiftData currently?

Comment: Custom Types are officially supported in SwiftData, provided they conform to Codable, as stated in the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/preservingyourappsmodeldataacrosslaunches)

As for how I'm creating the `CodedValue`, I'm just using Swift's `JSONDecoder`: 


`let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(CodedValue.self, from: jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!)`

Comment: That doesn’t mean it works since we’re using a beta version

Comment: I have a very similar issue, for me its saying `Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional<Any>' (0x1c1cee3d0) to 'Foundation.UUID' (0x1c1868058).` also in the Macro, but I've checked and I get the UUIDs correctly from the server, its only in SwiftData does it crash. 

What's also weird is it was working and I'm not sure what changed to make it not work now.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here:
[swift data crash solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76816305/crash-when-accessing-relationship-property-of-swiftdata-model)

Add `@Model` decorator to all of your models. And don't assign `CodedValue` model in the `Item` constructor. Because your app might crash. It's just a SwiftData bug.

```
let codedValue = CodedValue(string0: "", bool0: false, bool1: false)
let item = Item(timestamp: Date.now)
item.codableProp = codedValue
```

Comment: have you filed a radar for this bug? It seems to occur almost randomly

Comment: no, i think you are right. it occurs randomly :/

Comment: Have you noticed any more crashes with your solution?