# Crash when accessing relationship property of SwiftData model

Tags: swift-data

I have two one-to-many models and I'm getting an unexplained crash when trying to access the relationship properties of the models.

The reason for the error is as follows:

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1038f4448)

Xcode shows that the error occurs in the model's .getValue(for: .rows) method.
[image]

This is my SwiftData model:

```
@Model class Row {
    var section: Section?
    
    init(section: Section? = nil) {
        self.section = section
    }
    init() {
        self.section = nil
    }
}

@Model class Section {
    @Relationship(.cascade, inverse: \Row.section)
    var rows: [Row] = []
        
    init(rows: [Row]) {
        self.rows = rows
    }
}
```

This is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var container: ModelContainer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        do {
            container = try ModelContainer(for: [Section.self, Row.self])
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
              
        let row = Row()
        let section = Section(rows: [row])
        
        var myRows = section.rows    //Accessing relationship properties causes crash
        
        print("hello")  //no print
    }
}
```

If I access the relationship property of the model, the program crashes. Such as passing to a variable.

```
var myRows = section.rows
```

Or just printing the relationship property of the model also crashes

```
print(section.rows)
```

Xcode15 beta 5.

Comment: Really annoying, still present in Xcode 15.2 (macOS 14.3.1)
The two answers are not yet complete as I have a third case, during reading of relationship

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another bug in the SwiftData beta. It is related to the assignment of values even if in some circumstances the crash occurs when accessing the relationship propert. A workaround is to swap the assignment

```
let row = Row()
let section = Section()
row.section = section
```

I also changed the init so it for `Section` since passing and setting a relationship property in an init seems to be another issue.

Note that there was a bug in your code where you assigned the `row` object twice to the section.

Comment: Can I access the child model from the relationship property of the parent model after the swap assignment? Because I want to use parent model as ViewModel

Comment: Why shouldn’t you, it’s a bi-directional relationship.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I have smth like a `TweetModel.author: UserModel` and `UserModel.tweets: [TweetModel]`, but even making author optional (which doesn't really makes sense) didn't solve the issue, now I'm getting the same one on `TweetModel.author.set`...

Comment: @maximkrouk maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77500310/9223839) could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell SwiftData that you're using a delete rule like this:
@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var notes: [Note]