# SwiftData EXC_BREAKPOINT when setting relationship

Tags: swift-data

I'm working with SwiftData for the first time and having trouble with crashes when I try to set the value of a relationship.

I have a `Profession` object which represents a job in the game. Each `Profession` can have expenses (`Expense`, like a mortgage payment).

I'm trying to populate the initial data when the app first launches. When I'm creating the first `Profession`, I create one `Expense` which seems to work but when I create a second `Expense` the app crashes with `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1c3c6203c)` when trying to set the `Expense.profession` relationship. Xcode expands the `profession` property to show the get/set and it's crashing in the set function.

Am I missing something obvious? Or is SwiftData expecting me to do something very different than CoreData would in this case?

```
@Model
class Profession {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Expense.profession) var expenses: [Expense] = []
        
    init(name: String) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.name = name
    }
    
    convenience init(professiondefault: ProfessionDefault) {
        self.init(name: professiondefault.name)
        
        let taxes = Expense(name: "Taxes", cashflow: professiondefault.taxes, isPermanent: true, profession: self)
        
        // crashes on the next line
        let otherExpenses = Expense(name: "Other Expenses", cashflow: professiondefault.otherExpenses, isPermanent: true, profession: self)
        
    }
    
}


@Model
class Expense {
    let id: UUID
    var cashflow: Int
    let isPermanent: Bool
    var name: String
    
    var profession: Profession? 
    
    init(name: String, cashflow: Int, isPermanent: Bool, profession: Profession? = nil) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.cashflow = cashflow
        self.isPermanent = isPermanent
        self.name = name
        self.profession = profession
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Setting relationships in SwiftData seems to be problematic in some situations and then you need to try a different approach. First suggestion, when initializing Expense pass nil for Profession and set it directly afterwards instead. Try both ways if necessary. Second suggestion is to skip the convenience init altogether and do it in separate steps, perhaps combining it with the first suggestion.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried that too. I commented out all of the relationship stuff in the Profession init and then outside of the init, init'd the Expense without the profession, and once I set the profession on the Expense it crashed the same way... but again, only on the second expense. The first one works just fine. It's very confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe I have found a pattern for how to make this work. When creating two related objects at the same time then you need insert the one you want to assign to into your model context first before connecting the two

So this works

```
let profession = Profession(name: "New profession")
modelContext.insert(profession) // <-- Insert first
let expense1 = Expense(name: "Expense 1", cashflow: 10, isPermanent: false)
let expense2 = Expense(name: "Expense 2", cashflow: 10, isPermanent: false)
profession.expenses.append(contentsOf: [expense1, expense2])

// this is also ok 
//  profession.expenses.append(expense1)
//  profession.expenses.append(expense2)
```

And if we want to assign a profession to an expense this works:

```
let profession2 = Profession(name: "New profession")
let expense3 = Expense(name: "Expense 3", cashflow: 10, isPermanent: false)
let expense4 = Expense(name: "Expense 4", cashflow: 10, isPermanent: false)

modelContext.insert(expense3) // <-- Insert first
expense3.profession = profession2
modelContext.insert(expense4) // <-- Insert first
expense4.profession = profession2
```

Comment: Do you know how to get modelContext in recent SwiftUI?

Comment: It’s an environment object

Comment: Now it feels like I finally understood what does SwiftData want from me, the most helpful answer about SwiftData I've seen on the internet 

Comment: @JoakimDanielson do you mean I can use  <code>@Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext</code>   in < code>@Model class... </code> ?

Comment: No I never said that, you can never use `@Environment` outside of a view anyway. The best way to get access to a ModelContext object outside of a view depends on the use case, note that PersistentModel has a property `modelContex` that might be helpful inside a `@Model` class. But you should really post a proper question and explain what your issue is together with relevant code.