# SwiftData causes Xcode preview crash on array append

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I am using SwiftData for the first time with the follow model

```
enum AccountEntryValue: Codable {
    case number(CGFloat)
    case cadence(DuedateCadence)
    case date(Date)
}

@Model
final class AccountEntry {
    @Attribute(.unique) var uuid: UUID
    var entryDate: Date
    var data: [String: AccountEntryValue]
    init() {
        uuid = UUID()
        entryDate = Date.now
        data = [:]
    }
}

@Model
class AccountModel {
    @Attribute(.unique) var uuid: UUID
    let name: String
    var type: AccountType
    var entries: [AccountEntry]
    
    init(name: String, type: AccountType) {
        self.name = name
        uuid = UUID()
        self.type = type
        entries = []
    }
    
    func addEntry(_ entry: AccountEntry) {
        entries.append(entry)
    }
}
```

Which I initialize set up for my preview like so

```
#Preview {
    let config = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)
    let container = try! ModelContainer(for: AccountModel.self, configurations: config)
    
    return VStack {
        AccountView(model: AccountEntry())
    }.modelContainer(container)
}
```

And then I have code in there that goes

```
struct AccountView: View {
  var model: AccountModel
  var body: some View {
    Button("Add Entry") {
      model.addEntry(AccountEntry())
    }
  }
}
```

When I press the button "Add Entry" the swiftui preview canvas crashes and nothing printed out. I have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: What happens if you run the app, does it crash, do you get an error message?

Comment: I see now that `model` isn’t initialized in your preview code . Actually that code shouldn’t even compile.

Comment: No error message

Comment: Ah I missed something in my simplified version that makes it compile. My bad!

Comment: The problem is that you add a AccountEntry object to an AccountModel object before either of them is inserted into a model context. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77500310/9223839)

Comment: That was exactly it. Since the solutions are the same can I mark this as a duplicate of that one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftData EXC\_BREAKPOINT when setting relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77498274/swiftdata-exc-breakpoint-when-setting-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

The tip here about performing the .save first before appending to the array object within the object was kit.  It appears from my own testing in my application that you need not save it after that.  The frustrating thing is that the crash and the log (which is hidden away in a file somewhere) is not useful at all at explaining what the issue is.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35465680)