# SwiftData is not persisting the data relationships after the app closes

Tags: swift, combine, saving-data, swift-data

I have been researching this for days now but I can't find the answer....

I'm loading a single JSON file and decoding into 3 SwiftData classes
The loading and decoding works fine and the views of the app show the parent and children classes.  However, when I close the app, the relationships are lost.  I can see the children data in the sql database but they've lost the relationship to the parent so don't show up in the app as I traverse from the parent view to the children view(s).

The debugPrint (below) shows the child (method) of the parent (recipe) but it doesn't save it in SwiftData.  Any ideas?

```
func loadData (data: AnyPublisher<[Recipe], any Error>) {
    
    data
        .sink(
            receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.logger.error("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                case .finished: break
                }
            },
            receiveValue: { (recipes: [Recipe] ) in
                for recipe in recipes {
                    //insert the new recipe with the methods and ingredients
                    self.context.insert(recipe)
                    for method in recipe.method! {
                        debugPrint(method.step)
                    }
                }
                try? self.context.save()
                self.logger.notice("Successfully completed JSON decoding for Recipe:")
            })
        .cancel()
}
```

Extract of Classes:

```
@Model
final class Recipe: Codable {

enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    case name, source, ingredients, method
}

var name: String
var source: String

@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Ingredient.recipe)
var ingredients: [Ingredient]? = []

@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Method.recipe)
var method: [Method]? = []

@Model
final class Method: Codable {

enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    case order, step, stepComplete
}


var order: Int
var step: String
var stepComplete: Bool = false

//@Relationship(inverse: \Recipe.ingredients)
var recipe: Recipe?
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77500310/9223839) might be related. Unrelated perhaps but I would also catch and log any error when calling `context.save()`.

Comment: Thanks - I've added error catching and logging but the context.save() seems to be successful every time!

Comment: What do your data classes look like.  How are the relationships specified in that code?

Comment: Added extract of 2 classes..

Comment: Did you look at the linked answer?

Comment: Don’t make SwiftData objects Codable https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/maintaining-a-local-copy-of-server-data

Comment: Yes I did and I tried that approach but keep getting a crashes.  I think it must have something to do with the instance of the class outside the context (which has a temporary persistence ID) and the instance in the context.  I can't access the children of the temp ID (without a crash).  So I have to insert the parent into the context first but at that point I no longer have access to the children!!  Seems I'm in loop....

Comment: As mentioned, don’t use Codable directly and I would personally first make sure it worked fine without Combine.

Comment: Thanks Joakim, I will try that but do you have a hypothesis as to why removing Codable use directly will help?

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others, I found a solution...

I enabled CloudKit (in anticipation of working cross device) and so had to meet the requirements of optional or default values for properties.

The process of enabling CloudKit has managed to fix the issue so now the relationships persist!  This works even if not signed into iCloud on the simulator and works on a real device