# How to decode JSON file into SwiftData with relationships correctly?

Tags: json, swiftui, swift-data

The issue could be similar to that raised in another question: [Crash when accessing relationship property of SwiftData model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76816305/crash-when-accessing-relationship-property-of-swiftdata-model)

This is where the error was raised:

```swift
@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    // Below snippet is auto-generated by SwiftData
    var company: Company?
    {
    @storageRestrictions(accesses: _$backingData, initializes: _company)
        init(initialValue) {
                    _$backingData.setValue(forKey: \.company, to: initialValue)
                    _company = _SwiftDataNoType()
        }

    get {
                    _$observationRegistrar.access(self, keyPath: \.company)
                    return self.getValue(forKey: \.company)
                    //          ^ Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1) raised here
        }

    set {
                    _$observationRegistrar.withMutation(of: self, keyPath: \.company) {
                            self.setValue(forKey: \.company, to: newValue)
                    }
        }
    }
    // Codegen ends here
```

An example of the closure where the error was raised:

```swift
Text(app.jobDescription?.company?.name ?? "")
                        .font(.subheadline)
//                      -^ error raised when accessing this field
```

The referred question suggested a way to walk around as creating the two objects first then use an assignment to connect them, which seems to be impossible in the case of decoding a JSON file as the decoding is performed through nested calls to the constructors like this:

```swift
required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    guard let context = decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "modelcontext")!] as? ModelContext else {
            fatalError()
    }
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.company = try? container.decode(Company?.self, forKey: .company)
    //   ^ assignment here, how can this be lifted out of the `init` block?
    ...
    context.insert(self)
    //      ^ error is thrown in thread 1 when this function is called here
    }
```

Another interesting point is that the crashed thread is always the Thread 1, which seems to be the UI rendering thread. At the same time, another thread (typically thread 10 or 12) is calling `Model.init(from:)` where the Model is a model class defined by me. I am also wondering if there is something about the concurrency but no idea how to solve it.

If the `context.insert` is lifted, which means that no database action is performed during the `init` blocks but they are handled within the data import function, the error will be raised with same position (`self.getValue` and `EXC_BREAKPOINT`).

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
decoder.userInfo[modelContextKey] = modelContext
let decoded = try decoder.decode([Application].self, from: data)
                    
let results = decoded
                    
results.forEach {
    modelContext.insert($0)
    //           ^ error raised here in thread 1
}
```

Am I missing something important? How can I perform JSON decoding with SwiftData models properly in this case?

---

Update (as of Dec 10):

I think maybe I have found the cause of this issue. But I am not sure and I didn't find a solution.

The cause may be the one-to-many relationship which is (obviously) not mapped to my JSON scheme.

There are quite a few models but I may found something troublesome about the relationships of three models:

```
@Model
final class Application : Codable {
    @Relationship
    var jobDescription: JobDescription? = nil

    ... // some one-to-one relationships to simple models
    ... // or fields
}

@Model
final class Company : Codable {
    // complete class definition without fields
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \JobDescription.company)

    // **
    var positions: [JobDescription] = []

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case name, website
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let context = decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "modelcontext")!] as? ModelContext else {
            fatalError()
        }
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.website = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .website)
//        context.insert(self) // *1
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(website, forKey: .website)
    }
}

@Model
final class JobDescription : Codable {

    // *2
    @Relationship
    var application: Application? = nil

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var company: Company?

    ... // other fields
}
```

Regardless of the `@Relationship` annotations or how they are configured, the error was the same.

*1 If I uncomment this line and let it insert a `Company` into the context, the error will be raised near the `_$backingData.setValue(...)` call within the `init` part of the expanded code snippet, this is quite expected if I understand the things well.

*2 Regardless of the presence of this reference (there is already a one-to-one relationship), the error seems to be the same cause.

In other word, the relationships could be shown as the following (unrelated entities are omitted):

```
                   ┌─────────┐ 1
                   │ Company │┄┄┄┄┄╮
                   └─────────┘     ┆
                                   ┆ *
┌─────────────┐              ┌────────────────┐
│ Application │┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄│ JobDescription │
└─────────────┘ 1          1 └────────────────┘
```

As for the JSON file it should reflect an array of `Application` class like the following (with fields that I previously omitted):

```json
[
  {
    "cover" : {
      "createTime" : 723898052.629255,
      "content" : ""
    },
    "dateCreated" : 723898051.369947,
    "jobDescription" : {
      "responsibilities" : "",
      "company" : {
        "website" : "", "name" : "Apple"
      },
      "intro" : "",
      "type" : {
        "name" : "Front-end", "symbol" : null
      },
      "companyIntro" : "",
      "title" : "Frontend developer",
      "complementary" : ""
    },
    "events" : [
      {
        "type" : {
          "preparation" : { }
        },
        "updateTime" : 723898051.369947
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So there is an issue with the JSON scheme that I used for exporting data. (**) With this JSON file and if I remove the `var positions = []` relationship, the import feature works without any error. Unluckily, it will raise the same error around `getValue` call of the `company` field if there are more elements even though they have exactly the same structure.

So come back to the origin question (sorry for this very long text), I think I may got the idea of intermediate representations to facilitate the JSON decode (in case of one-to-many).

Comment: Personally I don’t think any of the Observable Macro types are meant to conform to Codable… at least not yet https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/maintaining-a-local-copy-of-server-data I know some people  force them to work but I don’t think they are meant to be.

Comment: It might be better with an interim type for decoding but this question is missing clarity, how is the other side of the relationship defined, what does the json look like that causes the error? I think it would be best to ignore concurrency issues for now and focus on the json decoding.